# Store unique values with Prisma and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, prisma

Let's say i have followed values in mongodb:

```
{ luckyNumber: 2 }
{ luckyNumber: 3 }
```

Now from outside i have `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, and i want to store just the unique numbers so the database should look like this:

```
{ luckyNumber: 1 }
{ luckyNumber: 2 }
{ luckyNumber: 3 }
{ luckyNumber: 4 }
{ luckyNumber: 5 }
```

How to store just the unique stuffs?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options either handle it at the application layer (which is what I recommend) or at the DB layer,

The easiest is doing this at the application layer, here is a way using [bulkWrite](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) with multiple updates for efficiency purposes, each update will either upsert a new document if it doesn't exist, or not change the existing document if it does.

```
const input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
cosnt updates = [];
input.forEach((num) => {
    updates.push({
        updateOne: {
            'filter': { luckyNumber: num },
            'update': { $setOnInsert: { luckyNumber: num } },
            'upsert': true,
        },
    });
});

db.collection.bulkWrite(updates)
```

If you prefer to let the DB handle this workload (which will affect update/insert performance) you can build a [unique index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/#:%7E:text=A%20unique%20index%20ensures%20that,the%20creation%20of%20a%20collection.) on the `luckyNumber` field, now you can just use `insertMany` on the input and the db will ensure only unique items are inserted:

```
const input = [1,2,3,4,5];
const structured = input.map((num) => ({luckyNumber: num}))
try {
    await db.collection.insertMany(structured, {ordered: false})
} catch (e) {
    // error will be thrown for unique conflicts
}
```

Note that it's important to use the `ordered:false` option to fully finish insertion, also that uniqueness conflicts actually throw an error so you will need to add error handling to separate between those and "actual" errors.